# Edit table row on button click meteor.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am adding details from a form inside a table but i am getting some issue while i click the edit button to update the selected row.

I want to edit the row such that the row becomes a textbox while clicking the edit button.

Here is the template:

```
<template name="empForm">
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <div class="row" style="margin-left:330px;">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="empName" style="height:40px;">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">   
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" style="height:40px;">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                    <label for="address">Address:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="address"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-style">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success">
                <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div><br>
        </form>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{#each emp}}
                <tr>
                    {{#if isdocumentId}}
                    <td><input type="text" name="{{empName}}"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="{{empEmail}}"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="{{empAddress}}"></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="remove-emp btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="edit-emp btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></a>
                    </td>
                    {{else}}
                    <td>{{name}}</td>
                    <td>{{empEmail}}</td>
                    <td>{{empAddress}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="remove-emp btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="edit-emp btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></a>
                    </td>
                    {{/if}}
                </tr>
                {{/each}}
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</template>
```

And this is my event handler:

```
'click .edit-emp': function()
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var documentId = this._id;
        var empNameDetail = $('[name=empName]').val();
        var empEmail = $('[name=email]').val();
        var empAddress = $('[name=address]').val();
        var confirm = window.confirm("Update Item?");
        if(confirm)
        {
            Employees.update({_id: documentId}, {set: {name: empNameDetail, empEmail, empAddress}});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: could you provide the sample rendered html from browser or table with sample data?

Comment: I have only one collection named 'Employees' where insertion and deletion works fine. it happens when i submit the form a table appears with the data i entered. In that data i have three fields namely 'name', 'email' and 'address'. I have attached two buttons edit and delete along with every table row that comes dynamically as a new data is inserted. But my edit button is not working

Comment: You want to your rows become textbox when you click edit button right?

Comment: Then inside `click event` try adding `$(this).closest('td').siblings().attr('contenteditable','true')`

Comment: it is still not working. can u elaborate more on 'contenteditable'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101247/discussion-between-ankush-rishi-and-guruprasad-rao).

Comment: what is your issues? try to add event in function params 'click .edit-emp': function(event). Did you have right to update?